# How to properly use Seek in DAO database

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I'm trying to search for currently selected item in my listbox control on my table.

In my listbox control after update event, I have this code

```
Private Sub lst_MainList_AfterUpdate()
    Dim theDB As DAO.Database
    Dim theProposalsTable As DAO.Recordset

    Set theDB = CurrentDb
    Set theProposalsTable = theDB.OpenRecordset("tbl_PROPOSAL", dbOpenDynaset)

    theSeeker theProposalsTable, Me.lst_PPpg_MainList.Value    
End Sub
```

Then I have a sub on my Module1 with this code. I got this from an example code @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836416.aspx

```
Sub theSeeker(ByRef rstTemp As Recordset, intSeek As Integer)

   Dim theBookmark As Variant
   Dim theMessage As String

   With rstTemp
      ' Store current record location.
      theBookmark = .Bookmark
      .Seek "=", intSeek

      ' If Seek method fails, notify user and return to the
      ' last current record.
      If .NoMatch Then
         theMessage = "Not found! Returning to current record." & vbCr & vbCr & "NoMatch = " & .NoMatch
         MsgBox theMessage
         .Bookmark = theBookmark
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

I am getting Runtime Error 3251 Operation is not supported for this type of object.

When I hit Debug, it highlights `.Seek "=", intSeek`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this point from the linked page ...

> Locates the record in an indexed table-type Recordset object

... *"table-type Recordset"* means you must use `dbOpenTable` instead of `dbOpenDynaset` with `OpenRecordset()`

That point is critical.  If you can't open the table with `dbOpenTable`, you can't use `Seek`.  And `dbOpenTable` can only be used with native Access tables contained in the current database.  It can not be used with any kind of linked table.

So if `dbOpenTable` is compatible with `tbl_PROPOSAL`, this change will eliminate the first error  ...

```vb
'Set theProposalsTable = theDB.OpenRecordset("tbl_PROPOSAL", dbOpenDynaset)
Set theProposalsTable = theDB.OpenRecordset("tbl_PROPOSAL", dbOpenTable)
```

If that does work, the next error will be #3019, *"Operation invalid without a current index."*  That happens because you must set the controlling index before calling `Seek` ...

```vb
With rstTemp
  ' Store current record location.
  theBookmark = .Bookmark
  ' Set the index. 
  .Index = "PrimaryKey" '<- use your index name here
  .Seek "=", intSeek
```

If you need to list the names of your table's indexes, you can examine its `TableDef.Indexes` collection.  Here is an Immediate window example with a table in my database ...

```vb
set db = CurrentDb
for each idx in db.TableDefs("tblFoo").Indexes : ? idx.name : next
id
PrimaryKey
```

Comment: I get Runtime Error 3219 Invalid Operation when I use `dbOpenTable`. I am using access 2016 just in case it matters

Comment: it is linked access tables. my front end is separated from my data. data is stored in one access file. front end is accessing it using link table manager but both are access database not SQL database. what else can I use to search for records if my setup is linked tables? will findfirst going to work?

Comment: Yes, `FindFirst` should work.  It does not require a "table-type Recordset".

Comment: yes this is certainly useful. if it is not possiblethen this is the answer to the question as it says "how to properly use..." if seek won't work in linked tables even if the linked table is access tables, then you had answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the **Seek** method on a linked table because you can't open linked tables as table-type Recordset objects...

However, you can use the Seek method if you use the OpenDatabase method to open the backend database.

So instead of:

```
Set theDB = CurrentDb()
```

Do this:

```
Set theDB = OpenDatabase("full path to backend database")
Set theProposalsTable = theDB.OpenRecordset("tbl_PROPOSAL", dbOpenTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to combine these two old answers. Yes, you get an error when opening a linked table as `dbOpenTable` because that is only supported on tables local to the DB object you are working on. Like David pointed out, you can open the linked backend as a DB object and use that.

I'm using a reliable table in my back-end called "Settings". If you don't have a reliable table you can use to pull the back end you can pass in the table name as an argument.

I'm storing the backend object once I have a handle on it so we can call against it rapidly throughout our code without recreating the object.

```
Private thisBEDB As Database

'@Description("This allows us to call directly against linked tables.")
Public Function thisBackend() As Database
    ' For MS-ACCESS table
    If (thisBEDB Is Nothing) Then
        With DBEngine
            Set thisBEDB = .OpenDatabase(Mid(CurrentDB.TableDefs("Settings").Connect, 11), False, False, "")
        End With
    End If
    
    Set thisBackend = thisBEDB
End Function
```

Now we can use the backend handle to make the code in your example work as expected.

```
Private Sub lst_MainList_AfterUpdate()
    Dim theDB As DAO.Database
    Dim theProposalsTable As DAO.Recordset

    Set theDB = CurrentDb
    Set theProposalsTable = thisBackend.OpenRecordset("tbl_PROPOSAL", dbOpenTable)

    theSeeker theProposalsTable, Me.lst_PPpg_MainList.Value    
End Sub

Sub theSeeker(ByRef rstTemp As Recordset, intSeek As Integer)

    Dim theBookmark As Variant
    Dim theMessage As String

    With rstTemp
        .Index = "PrimaryKey" 
        ' Store current record location.
        theBookmark = .Bookmark
        .Seek "=", intSeek

        ' If Seek method fails, notify user and return to the
        ' last current record.
      If .NoMatch Then
         theMessage = "Not found! Returning to current record." & vbCr & vbCr & "NoMatch = " & .NoMatch
         MsgBox theMessage
         .Bookmark = theBookmark
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```