# How to force an access query to use a binary search

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a very large database with a table that has more than 100 million records. All of the fields are integer numbers. Because I automatically import the data from another source, I guarantee that the records are sorted based on certain fields.

Is there any way to force access to use a binary search in some SQL statements where I want to speed up processes?

Comment: Are these fields Indexed?

Comment: Yes. My table has 6 fields, 1 is primary key, 4 are index to another table, and 6th is a double value.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that a binary search is going to be any faster then what the SQL data engine can do for you. You WILL however need an index on that column.

Even with 100 million rows, retrieval of one row should occur rather fast. What will NOT occur is if you have to re-run or re-pull “many” rows over and over. So it not clear how you are pulling this data.

However, if you have some type of looping code that needs to pull one row each time, then you can by-pass the SQL engine and use the seek() command on that index – this should produce much faster results then using SQL statements to pull that one row.

Note that seek () does not work on a linked table, but you can get around this limitation by creating an instance of the database object, and thus seek can be used even with linked tables.

The above assumes a jet/ace table here, not sql server.

So by-passing sql statements , and using a seek() command (with a index) would yield the best performance here – likely = to that of any custom function approach you build.

==== Edit ====

Edit:

The poster has also asked for a seek() with MORE than one key value.

So, lets assume we required to seek() on HotelName, and city.

And we want to by-pass sql for DIRECT use the indexing.

So, we need HotelName, and City, and want to seek() on these two key values.

You have to create what is a multi key index for this to work.
(not to be confused with a compound key index based on more then one column WHICH IS ALSO possible!!!).

So the way you do this is in design for the table – click on the indexes icon.

In the index dialog, you can then enter MORE THAN ONE column for the SINGLE index (this is critical for this to work).

The dialog will thus look like this:

[image]

So in above we have 5 indexs. However, note the index called HotelSearch. Note how we can enter MORE then one colum for the index.

You do this by leaving the index box name below “empty”

Also, the above is a example. I would STRONG suggest you dump any index not required (this is due to such high row counts – these indexs take up significant amounts of space – and you likely are already hitting close to max data file size of 2 gig here).

So note the two columns for the ONE index! We could of course add more columns (key values) to that index. Make sure you take into account the “order” of the columns, since you ONLY can have the extra columns as optional for a search, no skipping of prevous key values is allowed (so you can ony supply the first index colum, or several after at your desire - but no skipping is allowed).

So just leave the index name column box blank – that means the index “key” will apply to the ONE index for the seek().

What this means is that the two indexs NOW belong to the ONE index name.

So you have to plan somewhat here as to what is the critical index “group” that you going to see (and keep order in mind too).

Ok, now that we created that index name with multiple keys, we can now seek on TWO key values. Our code will look like this:

```
Sub SeekTest()

   Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset

   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_tblHotels2")

   With rst
      .Index = "HotelSearch"
      .Seek "=", "Holiday Inn", "Vancouver"

      If .NoMatch = False Then
         Debug.Print "found"
         ' got one!!!
      End If
   End With   

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that this approach is raw use of high speed indexing – and it will run at your processor “assembler” speed.

It will be anywhere from 100 to 1000 times faster than using SQL queries. It is blistering fast.

Comment: Never used seek before... Thanks! [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724293/how-to-properly-use-seek-in-dao-database)

Comment: Thanks Albert. I'll try it. But I don't need just one field, instead a group of data.

Comment: see my edit and follow up with more info in my answer - I show how to use a double key value for seek - you need this information.